# Redefine the environnment in order to have something visual

Tags: macros, environments

I usually write the definition using the predefined environnement definition, for instance:

```
\begin{definition}[THE WORD]
...
\end{definition}
```

I would like 2 things: firstly that the word definition is underlined in black (the same color as the word) and secondly that the word that appears afterward (the one in the []) is written in red.

After that, the definition of the element is directly written, is it possible to make it go under?  that you have on one line, and then only

```
" definition (the word).
blablabla..."
```

if finally i can do all those changement without changing my code (only applying modification at the beginning of the code, and keeping the style `\begin{definition}[THE WORD]`) it would be awesome

---

the options of my document are :

it is a book, i'm going to send you a pic just under, and for the packages I use there are so many... I assume that only the one for the boxes interest you :

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{fancybox}
```

but yeah I use all the others classic like tikz or the packages for mathematical content.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}
\input{../configuration/configuration}

\begin{document}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{fancybox}

\usepackage{shorttoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{{images/}}
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \setlength{\headheight}{15pt}


\usepackage{array}  




%%%%%%%%%%%%%% les boites !!!!


\newtheorem{remarque}{Remarque}[chapter] 


\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=section]{theoreme}[2][]{%
    colback=white!95!roug,
    colframe=roug,
    colbacktitle=white!80!roug,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries, 
    title=Théorème~\thetcbcounter.\ #2,
    enhanced,
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm, xshift=0.5cm},%
    #1% For possible options
}





\tcbset{
    thmbox/.style={
        enhanced,
        breakable,
        sharp corners=all,
        fonttitle=\bfseries\normalsize,
        fontupper=\normalsize\itshape,
         top=0mm,
         bottom=0mm,
         right=0mm,
        %colback=white,
        colframe=white,
        colbacktitle=white,
        %coltitle=red,
        attach boxed title to top left,
        boxed title style={empty, size=minimal, bottom=1.5mm},
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        overlay first={
            \draw (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);
            \draw (frame.north east)--(frame.south east);},
        overlay last={
            \draw ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-%
                  (frame.south east)--(frame.north east);},
        },
   %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    SV/.style={thmbox, coltitle=vert, colback=white!95!vert,
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw[vert][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw[vert][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay first={
            \draw[vert][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw[vert][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw[vert][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw[vert][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        },
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    SO/.style={thmbox, coltitle=oran, colback=white!95!oran,
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw[oran][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay first={
            \draw[oran][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        },   
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    LQ/.style={thmbox, coltitle=viol, colback=white!95!viol,
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw[viol][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);
            \node[anchor=east] at (frame.south east) {$\square$};},
        overlay first={
            \draw[viol][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw[viol][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);
            \node[anchor=east] at (frame.south east) {$\square$};},
    },  
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    SP/.style={thmbox, coltitle=oran, colback=white,
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw[oran][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay first={
            \draw[oran][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw[oran][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        },   
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    LR/.style={thmbox, coltitle=mauv, colback=white!95!mauv,
        overlay unbroken ={
            \draw[mauv][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east);
            \draw[mauv][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);
            \node[anchor=east] at (frame.south east) {$\square$};},
        overlay first={
            \draw[mauv][thick] (title.south west)--(title.south east); 
            \draw[mauv][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay middle={
            \draw[mauv][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)--([xshift=3.5mm]frame.south west);},
        overlay last={
            \draw[mauv][thick] ([xshift=3.5mm]frame.north west)|-([xshift=15mm]frame.south west);
            \node[anchor=east] at (frame.south east) {$\square$};},
    },  
}


\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within=section]{ajoutationV}{Exemple}{thmbox,SV}{theo}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within=section]{ajoutationO}{Exercice}{thmbox,SO}{theo}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within=section]{demo}{Démonstration}{thmbox,LQ}{theo}
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within=section]{solu}{Correction}{thmbox,LR}{theo}

\newtcbtheorem[auto counter, number within=section]{entrainement}{Entrainement}{thmbox,SP}{theo}


\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to give us something to start with? P.S. asking multiple questions in the same question should be avoided.

Comment: what about that?

Comment: Please have a look at this link: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228 Even after puzzling together your code fragments, there is no compilable code.

Comment: I don't understand... you gave me the same link twice... what do you need more ?

Comment: Please make a short but compilable document. Your code fragments cannot be compiled. The link contains instructions how to make a minimal **working** example.

Comment: is it this sufficient?

Comment: Your code still does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own theorem style, but please reconsider using underline, there are so many other (nice) ways to emphasis text.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}



\newtheoremstyle{Marine}% name 
{3pt}% Space above 
{3pt}% Space below 
{}% Body font 
{}% Indent amount 
{}% Theorem head font
{:}% Punctuation after theorem head
{\newline}% Space after theorem head 
{\underline{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}}\thmnote{ \textcolor{red}{ (#3)}}}% Theorem head spec (can be left empty, meaning ‘normal’)

\theoremstyle{Marine}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}[section]

\begin{document}


\begin{definition}[THE WORD]
test
\end{definition}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: underling isn't good ? you speak about other methods, do you have any example?

Comment: moreover thank you I'll use what you wrote to improve globally all the envrionnements I had coded. So thank you :)

Comment: @MarineGalantin Bold, colour, italic... everything is better than underlining.

Comment: okay. Can you just tell me how to increase the size of the word definition ? ( #1 and #2)

Comment: @MarineGalantin A bit exaggerated: `{\Huge \thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2}}`